# Conditional Probability for random variable (E(X))

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

**Need help with part b and c.**

We deal a hand of two cards (drawn at random) from a standard 52-card deck. Let the
random variable X represent the number of aces in this hand. Compute the following:
(a) E(X)
(b) E(X| the ace of ♠ is in this hand )
(c) E(X| at least one ace is in this hand ).

For part a, $x=0,1,2$
using the formula $^nCr=n!/(r!(n-r)!)$
$$P(x=0)= (4C0 *48C2)/(52C2) = 0.851$$
$$P(x=1)= (4C1 *48C1)/(52C2) = 0.145$$
$$P(x=2)= (4C2 *48C0)/(52C2) = 0.0045$$

$$E(X)= Σ(x*p(xi)=0.154$$

Where I'm running into issues with b and c. How would this need to be step up so that it can be solved.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: (a) .514 is way off!  .235 is answer.  For (b) and (c), other card is an ace?  What is probability?

Comment: For part (a) the expectation that a particular card in the hand is an ace is: $1/13$.  Expectation is Linear, so therefore expected count of cards in the hand of *two* cards is thus $2/13$. Which is $\approx 0.154$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For part a, $X\in\{0,1,2\}$ using the formula $^nC_r=n!/(r!(n−r)!)$

Parts b and c are much the same.  For part b, $X\in\{1,2\}$, because *when the $A\spadesuit$ is in the hand*, either the other card is not an ace, or it is; and the conditional probability for that is easy enough to determine.

When given that you have the ace of spades, the probability that you have no other ace is:  $$\mathsf P(X=1\mid A\spadesuit) =\dfrac{{^1C_1}{^{48}C_1}}{{^1C_1}{^{51}C_1}}=\dfrac{48}{51}\\\vdots$$

And so on, the same as you did before.

---

Likewise in Part (c) you just need to evaluate the probability of having only one ace when given you have *at least* one ace. $\mathsf P(X=1\mid X\geq 1)$

Which is not the same condition as knowing you have a specific ace, so take care.